# Jain Sip Stack using node.js Signalling Server

Tags: android, node.js, sip, sip-server, jain-sip

I have webrtc application and its signalling server is on node.js using socket.io. Now I am going to create android jain sip stack. I want to connect my webrtc application with jain sip application. 
My question is can I connect jain sip stack, using node.js server with websocket to connect to webrtc application? If Not, then how I build signalling sip server for jain sip stack that connect to webrtc?
I search alot about my question but I cannot find any proper guide or forum etc.

EDIT: I have found this stackoverflow link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985127/jain-sip-webrtc-signaling). But the answer is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io is a different (alternative) protocol and it's not compatible with SIP over websockets.

If you want to use SIP over websockets you can build both the server and the client part with JAIN-SIP stack as shown here [JAIN-SIP WebRTC signaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985127/jain-sip-webrtc-signaling) but you will have to ditch socket.io.

You can also consume socket.io with your own client library from android without having to use SIP just as well for webrtc. See [Java socket.io client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783086/java-socket-io-client). Beware socket.io has different versions so you have to match the versions you use right now as they are not very compatible.

Comment: Is there any book you can recommend for Jain-Sip?

Comment: JAIN-SIP is light SIP stack. Check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jain-sip-tutorial-149998.pdf to get the idea, but you must understand the SIP protocol before that. For SIP check the SIP RFC https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt or some simpler tutorial.